# How to add a cron task in his properly

Tags: php, cron

I have this folder:

```
/etc/cron.hourly
```

how can I add a simple task, for example:

```
php somefile.php
```

how to add a file that will execute it every hour inside that folder, using crontab, centos OS

Comment: hey, maybe this question goes more to superuser.com rather then stack overflow? not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a text file in that folder containing something like:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
include '/path/to/somefile.php';
?>
```

Where the first line contains the path to your php executable. After that you can use php like you would normally do.

Just keep in mind that the user running the script is probably not the same user that executes the php when you open a script from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Type 'crontab -e' at the command and add the following. This will execute every hour.

```
0 * * * * php -e somefile.php
```